# How to set some values on a class which is created by UINib in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a customised TableViewCell which can be created from Nib. In my table controller viewDidLoad() method, I add below code to register this Nib.

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "InputTableCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "InputCell")
```

My question is how I can set some values on this cell instance here?

Comment: You can't. You don't have a cell instance at this point. All you have done is associate a nib file with a reuse identifier. You will get cell instances when you dequeue cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: that means I have set these values inside cellForRowAtIndexPath? I wander how many table cell instances will be created. I assume there should be only one instance right? If not, why we need to call reuse function?

Comment: There will be one for each row that is on screen. As the table view scrolls, cells can be reused